# Bridge is not forwarding DHCP reply

Tags: forwarding, bridge, dhcp

My setup is as following:
Using kvm and tap-interfaces I have two vms running. The two tap-interfaces are connected via a bridge. On tap0 I have a DHCP-server running, on tap1 I executed a "dhclient".
Using tcpdump I got to know that tap1 sends a request, which is received by the server. The server replies. I can see the reply on the bridge interface, however the reply never gets to the client.

Also if I assign an IP to the client manually, I'm not able to ping in neither direction (server-client, client-server)

I have also tried setting all to 0 in /proc/sys/net/bridge/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you junction interfaces into a bridge, you no longer use the individual interfaces but the entire bridge as an interface.  You probably need to change your DHCP server to listen on `br0` instead of `tap0`.

If you don't have a `br0` or other similar bridge interface setup, you need to make one when you're using `tap` interfaces.  See the `brctl` command's `man` page.